# GSAP timeline needed on every page in Gatsby

Tags: layout, gatsby, gsap, react-forwardref

My Gatsby site use the same GSAP timeline on every page, so I want to stay DRY and my idea is to include my timeline in my Layout component in that order.

But I don't know how to pass refs that I need between children and layout using forwardRef.

In short, I don't know how to handle the sectionsRef part between pages and layout.
sectionsRef is dependant of the page content (children) but is needed in the timeline living in layout.

How can I share sectionsRef between these two (I tried many things but always leading to errors)?

Here's a codesandbox without the refs in the Layout:
https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-almeida-njt2e?file=/src/pages/index.js

And the sandbox with the refs in the layout:
https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-varahamihira-tc45m?file=/src/pages/index.js

Here's a simplified version of my files :
**Layout.js**

```
export default function Layout({ children }) {
  const containerRef = useRef(null);
  const sectionsRef = useRef([]);
  sectionsRef.current = [];

  useEffect(() => {
    gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger);

    const scrollTimeline = gsap.timeline();
    scrollTimeline.to(sectionsRef.current, {
      x: () =>
        `${-(
          containerRef.current.scrollWidth -
          document.documentElement.clientWidth
        )}px`,
      ease: 'none',
      scrollTrigger: {
        trigger: containerRef.current,
        invalidateOnRefresh: true,
        scrub: 0.5,
        pin: true,
        start: () => `top top`,
        end: () =>
          `+=${
            containerRef.current.scrollWidth -
            document.documentElement.clientWidth
          }`,
      },
    });
  }, [containerRef, sectionsRef]);

  return (
    <div className="slides-container" ref={containerRef}>
      {children}
    </div>
  );
}
```

**index.js** (page)

```
import { graphql } from 'gatsby';
import React, { forwardRef } from 'react';
import SectionImage from '../components/sections/SectionImage';
import SectionIntro from '../components/sections/SectionIntro';
import SectionColumns from '../components/sections/SectionColumns';

const HomePage = ({ data: { home } }, sectionsRef) => {
  const { sections } = home;

  const addToRefs = (el) => {
    if (el && !sectionsRef.current.includes(el)) {
      sectionsRef.current.push(el);
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      {sections.map((section) => {
        if (section.__typename === 'SanitySectionIntro') {
          return (
            <SectionIntro key={section.id} section={section} ref={addToRefs} />
          );
        }
        if (section.__typename === 'SanitySectionImage') {
          return (
            <SectionImage key={section.id} section={section} ref={addToRefs} />
          );
        }
        if (section.__typename === 'SanitySectionColumns') {
          return (
            <SectionColumns
              key={section.id}
              section={section}
              ref={addToRefs}
            />
          );
        }
        return '';
      })}
    </>
  );
};

export default forwardRef(HomePage);

export const query = graphql`
  query HomeQuery {
    // ...
  }
`;
```

Any clue greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Please make a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I'm wondering if it wouldn't be a lot more easy to use a template with gatsby-node in this case... I'm gonna try that.

Comment: So, as a workaround, I ended up generating page via a template with gatsby-node and a redirection from / to the generated page that is used as homepage... but I'm still interested by a more clever solution.